# Compatibility of camel.springboot and spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

How can I find out which spring-boot versions are supported by a given camel.springboot version? Neither camel-spring-boot-dependencies nor camel-spring-boot-bom contains any spring versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.apache.camel.springboot:spring-boot` pom file references a specific Spring Boot version. For example, [`3.10.0`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/springboot/spring-boot/3.10.0/spring-boot-3.10.0.pom) references Spring Boot 2.4.5, [`3.9.0`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/springboot/spring-boot/3.9.0/spring-boot-3.9.0.pom) references Spring Boot 2.4.4, and [`3.8.0`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/springboot/spring-boot/3.8.0/spring-boot-3.8.0.pom) references Spring Boot 2.4.2.